# How to define a Map with 'T'

Tags: java

I can define it with '?':

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends SuperClass>, String> map=
new HashMap<Class<? extends SuperClass>, String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 913392463302576279L;

    {
        put(SubClaas1.class, "sub1");
        put(SubClaas2.class, "sub2");
    }
};
```

But define with T, compile error:

```
private static <T extends SuperClass> Map<Class<T>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

How to define it use 'T' mode.

Comment: What is `T` supposed to be, who / what gives a value to `T`? If you want to use `T` you need to either declare it as a generic type parameter of the encapsulating class.

Comment: What makes you think that you want or need the form with the named type parameter (named `T` in your question)?

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm sorry to make you confused. I just feal 'T' type is more generic than '?' type.

Comment: Now I understand better why you asked. I certainly consider the form with `<?>` at least as generic. So my suggestion would be that you settle with it.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support declaring type parameters for individual fields, only for classes or methods.

You either need to move the declaration of `T` into the surrounding class itself, or keep using `Class<? extends SuperClass>` and do unchecked casts to whatever the appropriate type is.

Edit: Sorry, I just noticed that the field is static, in which case you can't just move the type parameter to the class. You need to stick to `Class<? extends SuperClass>`, either directly or by encapsulating the type unsafety in some custom class map.

Answer (score 1):

A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types.
It can be used for a class or a method, but not fields.

If you want to define a map with 'T':
a. use a method:

```
private static <T extends SuperClass> HashMap<T, String> generateMap() {}
```

b. use a method:

```
class Foo<T extends SuperClass> {
    private HashMap<Class<T>, String> map = new HashMap<Class<T>, String>();
}
```

Comment: About a.method, still get a compile error when I add line in 'generateMap()' 'map.put(SubClass.class,"sub");// error'

Comment: @SeaSwordWithWindShadow I updated the answer. Deleted 'Class<>' in return type. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a map of a type based on the needs of the method caller, eg:

```
   public static <T extends SuperClass> HashMap<T, String> giveMeMap() {
        return new HashMap<T, String>();
    }
```

so then this will complie:

```
private static HashMap<SuperClass, String> map = giveMeMap();
```

but this not, because of the type restriction on the method `<T extends SuperClass>`

```
private static HashMap<String, String> map2 = giveMeMap();
```

is this answering your question?

Comment: I need return a static HashMap<Class<? extends SuperClass>, String>. And init it with  'put(SubClass1.class,'sub1'); put (SubClass2.class, 'sub2')' in the function giveMeMap() body.